# How to create barplot from dataframe

Tags: r, bar-chart

I could not create barplot with following data frame

```
                    Age     Male.Average   Female.Average
   ---------------------------------------------------------    
1:       0-19 Childhood     20.29543       18.14773
2:    20-39 Young Adult     22.35352       22.41548
3: 40-64 Mid Aged Adult     23.75663       23.64908
4:     65-84 Senior Age     21.45002       21.71446
5:   85+ Old Senior Age     21.72200       21.31565
```

I want to create grouped barplot like x= age, y= male.average, female.average in beside. It gives error:

> Error in `barplot.default(d) : 'height' must be a vector or a matrix`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that we have a `data.frame`

```
barplot(`colnames<-`(t(df1[-1]), df1[,1]), beside=TRUE, 
    legend.text = TRUE, col = c("red", "green"), 
    args.legend = list(x = "topleft", bty = "n", inset=c(-0.05, 0)))
```

[image]